# remotely login into a linux system using java

Tags: java, linux

i want to remotely login into a linux system using java and then execute "df -h" command on that system,
I am currently using this code

```
        String[] cm = {
                       "ssh",
                       "root@192.168.1.10" ,
                       "df -h"

                       };

         try
          {
           Process q=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cm);
           q.waitFor();
          }
```

Everything is working well but the problem is that a pop up appears for entering the host password manually...how can i automatically enter password using the java code

Comment: You usually don't need to be `root` to run `df -h`, so I would avoid running `ssh root`

Comment: you probably can use `expect` command.

Answer (score 4):

Drop all that my friend and use the magnificent jsch:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

But if you insist on using a command line tool, then use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html) which is far more reliable, flexible and clear in the same time.

Comment: I would have but actually i dont have that much time.....if possible can u give a solution regarding my code only?

Comment: +1 using a real integrated ssh client is a better solution then relying on the local config.  Plus it is more portable (windows support)

Comment: @Somye Believe me if you spend a little time with that, you will actually save a lot of time in the future. And the project download has some samples to get you started fast. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure appropriately `ssh` e.g. thru `.ssh/config`, and you could have some public keys in `.ssh/authorized_keys`. Read carefully some good ssh tutorial, e.g. the [ssh tutorial for Linux](http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux) and many others web pages or even some good [ssh book](http://www.snailbook.com/).

Notice that you probably don't need to be root to run a `df -h` command, so I suggest to avoid being remotely root for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Although not best practice, if you really wish to do it through Java as asked, this is a solution to your question.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Test {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    String[] cm = {
        "ssh",
        "root@192.168.1.10" ,
        "df -h"
    };
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cm );
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
    out.write( "password".getBytes() );
  }
}
```

You could decide when to send the password based on what is read from the input stream if necessary.

Comment: it is not working..i am still getting a dialog box to enter the password

Comment: You should be able to run the ssh command in a shell only without a UI. There maybe a switch you need to provide with the ssh command. I'm not an expert on Linux/SSH so I can't help there. Good luck!